# Need help to configure PIE.htc for CSS3

Tags: html, css, css3pie

I found out that using PIE.htc will hellp to resolve the problem with IE7-8 when using box shadow.

I did exactly as they are explaining on the official website: http://css3pie.com/

But I can't get it to work on IE7 and IE8:

this is my code:

```
.shadow {
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #696;
    text-align: center; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: #666 0px 0px 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #666 0px 0px 5px;
    box-shadow: #666 0px 0px 5px;
    background: #EEFF99;
}
<div class="shadow">
    Example
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your `PIE.htc` file in the same directory where you have put your html and hopefully it will work.

```
behavior: url(PIE.htc);
```

according to [Documentation](http://css3pie.com/documentation/getting-started/)

> Of course you will need to adjust the path to match where you uploaded PIE.htc in step 2. Note: this path is relative to the HTML file being viewed, not the CSS file it is called from.

Reference Images: [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMgsj.png)
   [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTBR4.png)

Comment: It is in the same directory. I even created a test folder where i store those file

Comment: You need just `PIE.htc` and your `html` file in same directory and it will work. i have tested it on my machine with just these two files.

Comment: you tested it with IE7 & 8?

Comment: I have added two images for your reference

Comment: yes @AndrewS but it really strange. everything looks perfect with your images as well. We can do one more thing just clear the cache of the browser (ctrl+F5) may be it is a culprit :)

Comment: I tryed this many time.. its not because of cache... I am really confused, I alwasy loose time on such simple, with no reason probplems...

Comment: I have no idea whats wrong!!! could it be a problem in my IE? I downloaded it from Microsoft today.

Comment: may be @AndrewS it's really should not happened. Make sure you have put `PIE.htc` not any other files in place of this. otherwise make new example and download new files from here again.http://css3pie.com/documentation/getting-started/ :)

Comment: I have an idea, ill try it on another PC... Who knows, it could be, ill get back with the result!

Comment: Well, my pc or my IE is doing smthing wrong... I checked out on two different PC with different OS w7 and Xp, on both works perfect.. So the problem is in my machine, ill figure it out... Thanks Sachine!!!

Comment: Wow great. I am so happy after solving this strange problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Give .shadow{ position: relative}

For PIE to work properly, give it a position through CSS.